# Open jar file with cmd

Tags: windows, jar, cmd, java

I have a jar file named "adventure.jar".  When you run it through the cmd with `java -jar adventure.jar` it works fine.  However, I am testing opening the file on a new computer, and I am encountering a problem.  This computer doesn't have the `java` command in the command prompt.  It defiantly has Java installed, but maybe just not the JDK?  Anyway, my goal is to make the jar file run from cmd when double clicked, without the need of commands (is that even possible?).  The jar is already executable, but it doesn't execute from the command prompt like I need.  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:  If there is a way to do this through an exe or batch file I'd be fine with that, too.

Comment: Did any of the answers below resolve this question? or are you still seeing the error?

Comment: btw..never call your batch file "start.bat". It conflicts with start command that already exists in windows.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your PATH env. variable doesn't have Java in it.    You can add it by following Oracle's tutorial

[Adding Java to your PATH Environment variable.](http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Usually it's something like `;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin`

To your second question - yes it's possible.
Open up notepad, then type `java -jar adventure.jar` then save it as `launch.bat` or something.  then you are able to double click that batch file, which will run your java archive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  However, I can't modify the computer that I've loaded the jar file on (like the path) because I am trying to make this distributable, where anyone can double click the jar and it runs.  On the second part of your answer, you use the `java` command, and that's the impossible part for me.  I already tried making batch files, but this computer doesn't have that command.  If you type 'java' it says it's not a recognizable command.  I know it has Java though, I am able to run applets, Java programs, and enter the Java control panel.  Is it a problem with the computer?

Comment: If you can't modify that computer, then what you can do is on the first line of your batch file, type - `PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin` or wherever your java is installed.  That means "for this program i want to include anything under `\bin`.  Which includes the `java` executable.

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt

Go to the folde where jar file is located

Run

```
unzip test.jar
```

here **test.jar** is name of the jar file.

This command  will unzip all the file into that folder

Answer (score -1):

First, try `start adventure.jar` from Command Prompt. If that does not work, locate `java.exe` (on my computer, `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin`) and either use the full path in Command Prompt, or add the path to the folder containing `java.exe` to your `PATH` environment variable. To add the path, click Start Menu, right-click Computer, click Properties, click Advanced System Settings, click Environment Variables, then find `PATH` under System Variables and click Edit, and add the path (example: add the following onto the end of PATH: `;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin` and don't forget the semicolon!)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't modify the computer that has the jar, because my goal is to be able to distribute the jar so anyone can just double click on it.

Comment: Well, on most or all Windows machines, `.jar` files will start automatically when double clicked, because java setup installs a registry key that tells Windows to open `.jar` files with `java.exe`.